# Drupal: Multilingual SEO website

Tags: 7

I am trying to build a simple website with a blog. The website needs to have, at least, 4 languages and SEO optimization (Title Description Keywords). 
Please advise me on which modules to use and if there is any how-to tutorials to do so. Are there any pre-made profiles I can use?
In the end I would like to create a profile which I will replicate for feature projects.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks to find, recommend, or suggest hosting providers, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a multilingual Drupal 7 site you could enable the Locale and Content translation modules, they are both included in the Drupal Core.

Also, you might want to check the [Internationlization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module and the [Entity translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module.

Basically you start of by adding languages to your site, you can do this in the administration area (/admin/config/regional/language). After that you can allow content types to be translated (/admin/structure/types). When you add a node you will then be able to choose between the enabled languages.

As for SEO: you could check the [Drupal SEO Tools](http://drupal.org/project/seotools), it has a huge list of modules that you can use.